# Formula Field issue1

Tags: formula, formula-field, image-formula

I need to write a formula where if some conditions are true it should display one image and if the same conditions and an added one is true it should display another image.
So far I have this but something seems wrong:

```
IF(
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value1"),
        ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value2"),
        ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value3"),
        ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value4")
    ),
    IMAGE(image URL, alternate text, height, width), 
    ""
),
IF(
    AND(
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value1"),
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value2"),
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value3"),
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value4")
        ), 
        field2 = "Text"
    ),
    IMAGE(IMAGE(image URL, alternate text, height, width)
    ""
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Hopefully someone here can help you, but please note that If you write your Formulae like they are code - as @DerekF showed in the edit he made to your question - that can go very far in helping initially write them and/or debug them.

Answer (score 1):

IF statements are evaluated in order, and your second set of conditions will always be met by the first set. You'll need to swap the order of evaluation, nest your statements and have a default return value in case neither is true. Something like this, where the default would just be blank:

```
IF(
    AND(
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value1"),
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value2"),
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value3"),
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value4")
        ), 
        field2 = "Text"
    ),
    
    /*This is the image of your initial second condition*/
    IMAGE(image URL, alternate text, height, width),
    
    IF(
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value1"),
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value2"),
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value3"),
            ISPICKVAL(field1__c,"value4")
        ),
        
        /*This is the image of your initial first condition*/
        IMAGE(image URL, alternate text, height, width),
        
        /*This is the default return value if neither condition is met*/
        ""
    )
)
```